# Длинная арифметика (сложение)

Tags: c, длинная-арифметика

Я нашёл код, который позволяет складывать два длинных числа длиной до 100 символов. Как сделать так, чтобы можно было складывать два длинных числа длиной до 10000 символов?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
  
#define MAX_NUMBER_LEN 126
  
void input_big_number(char *number);
  
  
void output_big_number(char *number);
  
  
void add_big_numbers(char* sum, const char *a, const char* b);
  
  
int main()
{
    char a[MAX_NUMBER_LEN];
    char b[MAX_NUMBER_LEN];
    char c[MAX_NUMBER_LEN];
  
    memset(a, 0, MAX_NUMBER_LEN);
    memset(b, 0, MAX_NUMBER_LEN);
    memset(c, 0, MAX_NUMBER_LEN);
  
 
    input_big_number(a);
    input_big_number(b);
 
    add_big_numbers(c, a, b);
  
    output_big_number(c);
  
    printf("\n");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
  
  
void input_big_number(char *number)
{
    char buffer[MAX_NUMBER_LEN];
    char i, j, k;
  
    fgets(buffer, MAX_NUMBER_LEN, stdin);
  
    if (buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] != '\n') {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  
    buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';
  
    k = strlen(buffer) - 1;
    for(i = k; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        number[k - i] = buffer[i] - '0';
    }
}
  
  
void output_big_number(char *number)
{
    char i, j, k;
  
    for(k = MAX_NUMBER_LEN - 1; number[k] == 0 && k > 0; k--);
  
    for(i = k; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d", number[i]);
    }
}
  
  
void add_big_numbers(char* sum, const char *a, const char* b)
{
    char carry = 0;
    char w = 0;
    char t;
    char i, j, k;
  
    for (t = 0; t <= MAX_NUMBER_LEN; t++)
    {
        w = a[t] + b[t] + carry;
        carry = w / 10;
        sum[t] = w % 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: прописать в `#define MAX_NUMBER_LEN 126` правильную длину?

код отлично форматируется.

Comment: @KoVadim, насчет отлично, Вы загнули.

@MahovIV, главное в местном форматировании это (почти как в FORTRAN IV) 4 пробела перед каждой строчкой кода. И желательно табуляции в нем заменить на пробелы.

Comment: а ещё есть случай, когда даже 4 пробела вначале не помогают. Это когда перед этим список.

Comment: @avp а indent (например indent -linux) уже не котируется?

Comment: @alexlz, это замечательный инструмент, но добавлять пробелы и делать untabify все равно придется.

Answer (score 2):

Если есть возможность — не изобретайте велосипед, примените готовую и хорошо отлаженную библиотеку [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

---

Если вы всё же хотите сделать всё самостоятельно (например, для практики), 
перейдите на динамической размер чисел — то есть, такой тип данных:

```
struct bignunm_t
{
    size_t number_of_digits;
    unsigned char* digits;
};
```

Таким образом, у вас будет переменное количество цифр.

Операции, конечно, станут немного сложнее:

```
bignum_t add(bignum_t l, bignum_t r)
{
    bignum_t result;
    result.number_of_digits = max(l.number_of_digits, r.number_of_digits) + 1;
    result.digits = malloc(result.number_of_digits * sizeof(unsigned char));
    size_t common = min(l.number_of_digits, r.number_of_digits);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < common; i++)
        result.digits[i] = l.digits[i] + r.digits[i];
    for (size_t i = common; i < l.number_of_digits; i++)
        result.digits[i] = l.digits[i];
    for (size_t i = common; i < r.number_of_digits; i++)
        result.digits[i] = r.digits[i];
    result.digits[result.number_of_digits - 1] = 0;
    // fixup
    for (size_t i = 0; i < result.number_of_digits - 1; i++)
    {
        if (result.digits[i] > BASE)
        {
            result.digits[i] -= BASE;
            result.digits[i+1]++;
        }
    }
}
```